# Creating friendly url in php using slim framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim

I want to open profile page like `www.website.com/slim/username` (where `username` is unique) .

I am currently using `slim php` framework for routing `GET` requests. So when I open `www.website.com/profile/username` it properly executes the route defined for `/username` and gives simple json response like  this

```
{"users":[{"id":"01","firstname":"kamron","lastname":"shaw","gender":"male","status":"Offline"}]}
```

From this point I wanted to integrate this data with the profile page template, so I made a profile page template at `www.website.com/profile.php` and from there used `ajax` to make a `GET` request to
`www.website.com/slim/username` and receive data and display it with template.

Problem is that if a user navigates directly to `www.website.com/slim/username`, he will only see the raw `JSON` response.

I want users to see the `JSON` response with template when they directly make a `GET` request from there browser.

How can I achieve this? Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere and tell me a suitable way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`$isXHR = $app->request->isAjax();`
or
`$isXHR = $app->request->isXhr();`
to check the request is ajax or not. If not ajax than redirect to the page you want ( may be profile if logged in, or login page if not logged in )

```
if($isXHR){
   echo 'json';
}else{
   render view
}
```

Comment: But I do want users to see the profile like in facebook .

Comment: What I understand is that:
this url `www.website.com/slim/username` gives JSON data 
this url `www.website.com/profile.php` gives the template

But you want to display Profile page on this url `www.website.com/slim/username` also 

So don't redirect if the request is not ajax. render the template.

Comment: what if a user wants to see the profile of other member? The user should see the same template with different firstname, lastname gender etc .. when he opens " www.website.com/slim/username "

Comment: How you are  rendering the user details into the template?
Is the template a static ? You have to get the user details using the username ( url param ) and pass to the view and render it. 
Or you can load the user details via ajax cal to the url on load.

Comment: yes, I am loading the user details via ajax call to the url(www.website.com/slim/username) on load using jquery on "www.website.com/profile.php " under <script> tags . And yes, one user can properly view his profile with his details, but only when he makes request from "profile page" . If he directly opens "www.website.com/slim/username" he will not see any template . In simple words, I want it to be like in facebook, if you open "facebook.com/username" ,you see your profile and when you open "facebook.com/zuck", you see another .If my approach is incorrect, please correct me.